# Throttling for api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, throttling

I am trying to enable throttling for api-gateway. I created and deployed my api gateway at a stage. Now, I followed AWS document and ran

```
aws apigateway create-usage-plan \
--name "test" \
--api-stages file://stage.json \ 
--throttle file://base.json
```

stage.json

```
[
    {
        "apiId": "my-id",
        "stage": "dev",
        "throttle":{
            "/v1/test/GET": {
                "burstLimit": 50,
                "rateLimit": 200.0
            }
        }
    }
]
```

base.json

```
{
    "burstLimit":10,
    "rateLimit":5
}
```

I see that I got the JSON output and I can also see the plan under usage plan. But, then, when I see default-method-throttling under stages, it has not changed.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the **stage-level throttling**. But you are setting the throttling for one specific resource and method `/v1/test/GET`. So you have to check throttling setup for that specific path (not for the entire stage).

Comment: It says `default method throttling`. Also `base.json` should be stage level throttling?

Comment: @amyJ Yes, but you overwrote the default setting  for `/v1/test/GET`. Can you maybe provide more screenshots for the `/v1/test/GET`. Your current screenshot is cropped so its not clear to where it applies.

Comment: I added the screen shot from usage plan which has my API associated with it. I clicked `Configure method throttling` -> `vi/test/GET` endpoint throttling limits are added above. Also the screen shot which was added earlier is NOT cropped. That is all I see in stage editor [stages->settings]

Comment: @amyJ usage plan limits are seperate from stage limits. So I'm not sure what do you want to achieve. Change stage limits, usage plan limits or method limits?

Comment: For reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html clearly states `Configuring API-level and stage-level throttling in a usage plan` which is what I did. The default method throttling will/should be overridden via usage plan method throttling. I think the throttling limits are just account level throttling per region. I would be more than happy to change that as well via config files if possible rather than console.